# Showing multiple result sets in Teradata Studio

Tags: teradata

I'm new to Teradata Studio and have used SQL Assistant in the past.  I can find no way of showing multiple result set windows.
Googling refers to a button to switch from tab to sash display - which looks as if it might be what I want, but that button does not exist on my toolbar.
I'm trying to make Studio do what SQL Assistant does.

Comment: If I select multiple queries in the SQL Editor, and run them as individual statements, I get two result sets.  If I run them as a single statement, I get the back as a single result set, with two tabs in it. The tab to sash thing only shows up if I run multiple queries as a single statement.

Comment: Also be sure Window / Preferences / Teradata Datatools / Result Set Viewer has the "Reuse Result Set Viewer Window" option un-checked.

Comment: Fred : Thanks, I had this unchecked.

Comment: Andrew : Thanks, I managed to reproduce this and it is nothing like the kind of flexibility that the old SQL Assistant had.  So I think that I have to assume that Teradata Studio just doesn't have the capability of their older product - pretty disappointing really.

Answer (score -1):

to have multiple answerset you have to :
=> run the query and right click on th result cell with the mouse and choose "Do not Close"

the next query that you excute will display an other answerset

if you want to excute a third query then you have to do the same thing